# angular directive won't update two-way binding with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I have a modal directive that should become visible when a button is pressed. however, the value responsible for determining whether the modal should be open that is two-way bound with the directive does not seem to update. any ideas?

here is the directive JS:

```
function modalDialogSelect() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    templateUrl: "./views/directive_templates/select_modal.html"
  };
 }
```

directive Inner HTML URL:

```
<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
  <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
    <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
      <p>Select New Customer</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the button to click and open the modal:

```
<button ng-click='selectCustomer = true;'>SELECT/CREATE CUSTOMER</button>
```

and the modal-dialog-select directive in my general HTMl

```
<modal-dialog-select show='selectCustomer'></modal-dialog-select>
```

any ideas why scope.show isn't updating in my directive? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to change the `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {...}` block in your directive's configuration for a `controller: function($scope) {...}`? Same code inside, but changing `scope` for `$scope`.

Comment: @ggalmazor Wouldn't make a difference.  You can name the variables whatever you want, the issue here is something else.

Comment: no luck changing from link to controller.... trying the other things you've suggested!

Comment: @austin809 I deleted that comment because I misread something.

Comment: @ggalmazor I'm pretty sure I'm not; please, find me documentation that supports your theory; the variable naming only matters in the directive/service/controller/app creation, where angular basically figures out what imports we need via names.  Here, we aren't importing anything.  As to my other comment, as I already stated, **there is a reason I deleted it.**

Comment: @Daedalus please forgive me if I'm not understanding you... Angular passes params on link functions by position: `scope, element, attributes, controller`. On controllers defined like in the OP's example (not using the array form, annotations or the `$inject` property), params are passed matching their names with known objects on Angular's dependency injection container. Anyway, my point was to use a controller and not a link function to avoid possible problems with premature scope binding that can occur under weird circumstances (with modals especially) in my experience.

Comment: @austin809, could you try to store the boolean value of selectCustomer in a property of an object in the parent scope? So that the html reads like: `<modal-dialog-select show='someObj.selectCustomer'></modal-dialog-select>`

Comment: @austin809 What version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: @ggalmazor no luck there.

Comment: @austin809 Did you previously migrate to 1.3.x from an out of date version?

Comment: I assume you actually have a scope variable in your controller such as: $scope.selectCustomer = false?  Because it works fine for me.

Comment: @Daedalus nope. always been using 1.3.x

Comment: There is a problem in the modal's template. You need to remove one of the last `</div>`. I've prepared a [codepen](http://codepen.io/ggalmazor/pen/jPZOvZ) with your example and everything seems to work after that change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a problem in your modal's template that was producing

```
Error: Template must have exactly one root element. was: 
<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
  <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
  <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
    <p>Select New Customer</p>
  </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

After removing the last `</div>` everything works.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectCustomer = false;
});

app.directive('modalDialogSelect', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    templateUrl: "modal.html"
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ParentController"> 

  <p>Flag is: {{selectCustomer}}</p>
  <button ng-click='selectCustomer = !selectCustomer'>SELECT/CREATE CUSTOMER</button>

  <modal-dialog-select show='selectCustomer'></modal-dialog-select>


  <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
    <div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'>
      <div class='ng-modal-overlay' ng-click='hideModal()'></div>
      <div class='ng-modal-dialog' ng-style='dialogStyle'>
        <p>Select New Customer</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be that fun issue of javascript passing by value since the the var is a bool.  Honestly, I'm bad at explaining the root cause on this one.

Try passing it as an object

```
ng-click='selectCustomer.value = true'
```

Then your show scope property would be scope.show.value.

Comment: i assume you were still passing the variable as

    <modal-dialog-select show='selectCustomer'></modal-dialog-select>

Comment: @RickWillis I was guessing this could be the problem too... could you write the full code example with the html for the button and the modal usage  with the use for the OP, please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine...

```js
function modalDialogSelect() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
      show: '='
    },
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.dialogStyle = {};
      scope.hideModal = function() {
        scope.show = false;
      };
    },
    template: "<div class='ng-modal' ng-show='show'><button ng-click='hideModal()'>Here's the Modal</button></div>"
  };
}

angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('testCtrl', function() {})
  .directive('modalDialogSelect', modalDialogSelect);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="testCtrl as vm">

    <button ng-click='vm.selectCustomer = true;'>SELECT/CREATE CUSTOMER</button>

    <modal-dialog-select show='vm.selectCustomer'></modal-dialog-select>

  </div>
</div>
```